Passing functions between screens in expo routing, react native
I'm starting to use react native and trying to pass a setState function from one screen to another using the expo routing:
...
 const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
...



<Pressable
  onPress={() => 
    router.push({
      pathname: "/page2",
      params: {message: message, method: setMessage},
     })
   }
...

however when I go to use the function in page2, i get the error message:

method is not a function (it is 'function bound dispatchSetState(a0) { [bytecode]}')

How can I pass functions between screens in react native?
Alternatively how do you go about changing the state in a homescreen from a screen further down the stack.
I tried passing the function in to the params object like a variable but got an error

See what should be in params: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params.

I think this is not a better way to do what you want to do.
The better way is leave the PARAMS as objects and let the /page2 with the function receiving the PARAMS.
<Pressable
  onPress={() => 
    router.push({
      pathname: "/page2",
      params: {message: message},
     })
   }

And in the /page2 leave like this
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.message) {
     setMessage(route.params?.message)
    }
  }, [route.params?.message]);

return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Message: {message}</Text>
</View>);

then use message variable to do what you want to do!
ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params
Hope this help!
